# c# Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Не могу справиться с проблемой При вводе любых данных получаю ошибку Индекс находился вне границ массива в строке.

```
B[1] = St[maxi][(St[maxi].Length)];
```

Весь код

```
private void Make_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Nk, i, j, N, K, Len, P, max, maxi, L, T;
            String Lozung;
            long[] A;
            char[] B;
            A = new long[1000];
            B = new char[1000];
            Nk = 0;
            Lozung = "solve";
            string[] St;
            St = new string[10];
            N = 4;


            St[0] = "set";
            St[1] = "owe";
            St[2] = "evil";
            St[3] = "too";

            K = 0;
            Len = Lozung.Length;
            do
            {
                T = K;
                if (K == 0)
                {
                    max = 0;
                    maxi = 1;
                    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
                    {
                        L = St[i].Length;
                        P = 0;
                        for (j = 1; j < L; j++)
                        {
                            if (St[i][j] == Lozung[P + 1])
                            {
                                P++;
                            }
                            if ((P > max) || ((P == max) && ((St[maxi].Length) > L)))
                            {
                                max = P;
                                maxi = i;
                            }
                        }
                        Nk = 1;
                        A[1] = maxi;
                        B[1] = St[maxi][(St[maxi].Length)];
                        K = max;
                    }

                    max = 0;
                    maxi = 1;
                    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
                    {
                        if (St[i][1] == B[Nk])
                        {
                            L = St[i].Length;
                            P = K;
                            for (j = 2; j < L; j++)
                            {
                                if (St[i][j] == Lozung[P + 1])
                                {
                                    P++;
                                }
                                if ((P > max) || ((P == max) && (St[maxi].Length > L)))
                                {
                                    max = P;
                                    maxi = i;
                                }
                            }
                            Nk++;
                            A[Nk] = maxi;
                            B[Nk] = St[maxi][(St[maxi].Length)];
                            K = max;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            while ((T == K) || (K >= Len));
            {
                if (T == K)
                {
                    outTextBox.Text = ("?");
                }
                for (i = 1; i < Nk; i++)
                {
                    outTextBox.Text = St[A[i]].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Правильный ответ программы должен быть - "?".
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: вне границ массива, значит где-то ты её превышаешь. Где именно - воспользуйся отладкой, посмотри, что где у тебя в коде происходит на каждой строчке, а точнее на той строке, на которой и выскакивает исключение

Comment: А что этот код вообще делает? У меня впечатление, что этот код сильно переусложнён и запутан, всё это наверняка можно гораздо проще, короче, и главное понятнее сделать. А у вас тут нужно думать, что такое `L`, `K`, `T`, `P` и прочее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B[1] = St[maxi][(St[maxi].Length-1)];
```

Length возвращает количество символов, проще говоря например ваша строка хранит "Hello" длина будет 5, но подсчет индексов начинается с 0, следовательно максимальный индекс в строке это 4

Поэтому вам надо ставить

```
Length-1
```